# How do I access the OpenApi endpoint in WildFly 18+?

Tags: wildfly, openapi, microprofile

I have a war with MicroProfile OpenApi annotations. When I run it on Payara or OpenLiberty, I can access the OpenApi document at http://localhost:8080/openapi, as specified in the spec.

This does not work on WildFly 18 nor on 19 Beta 1, even though it claims to support MP OpenApi. I suppose the TCK would check for that, so maybe I'm doing something wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the OpenAPI support was added with [WildFly 19 Beta 1](https://issues.redhat.com/browse/WFLY-12313?_sscc=t). Unfortunately, the current documentation on the wildfly.org page is for WildFly 18 and does not include an admin guide for including OpenAPI.

Nevertheless, you can find the `.adoc` file for the OpenAPI support [on GitHub](https://github.com/wildfly/wildfly/blob/master/docs/src/main/asciidoc/_admin-guide/subsystem-configuration/MicroProfile_OpenAPI.adoc). Based on the history of this file, it was added in December 2019 (that's maybe why I didn't make its way to the documentation on the homepage yet).

The current documentation for OpenAPI claims to be part of the default `standalone-microprofile.xml` configuration and the document is available at http://localhost:8080.

If you don't run with this configuration, you can enable the OpenAPI subsystem with the following commands (which I tested with WildFly 19 Beta 1):

```
➜  bin ./jboss-cli.sh 
You are disconnected at the moment. Type 'connect' to connect to the server or 'help' for the list of supported commands.
[disconnected /] connect
[standalone@localhost:9990 /] /extension=org.wildfly.extension.microprofile.openapi-smallrye:add()
{"outcome" => "success"}

[standalone@localhost:9990 /] /subsystem=microprofile-openapi-smallrye:add()
{
    "outcome" => "success",
    "response-headers" => {
        "operation-requires-reload" => true,
        "process-state" => "reload-required"
    }
}

[standalone@localhost:9990 /]
```

Please note: If you then try to access it at http://localhost:8080/openapi in your browser, you might get a 406 - Not Acceptable. Just request it the correct content-type or using `cURL`:

```
curl -v http://localhost:8080/openapi // YAML output
curl -v http://localhost:8080/openapi?format=JSON  // JSON output
```

Comment: I meant 19.x... sorrry for the confusion. I don't see a `standalone-microprofile.xml` in `standalone/configuration`.
Adding the configuration worked (after the reload).

Comment: Don't forget to reload the wildfly server to apply the changes.